# Brainfuck to NASM compiler in Haskell

Tags: haskell, assembly, brainfuck, compiler

After reading [this article](https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/write_yourself_a_brainfuck.md) on writing a Brainfuck interpreter in Haskell and achieving awful performance with it (for example, [mandelbrot](https://github.com/ErikDubbelboer/brainfuck-jit/blob/master/mandelbrot.bf) generating **37.5 minutes** on an old Intel Atom powered laptop) I've decided to write a compiler for it.

I picked [NASM](https://nasm.us) for my output language, because that is the only assembly language I somewhat understand, and after some problems ([resolved in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616492/why-does-a-program-created-by-a-brainfuck-into-assembly-compiler-crash)) I've finally arrived with a working compiler!

I would like get more feedback about good coding practices in Haskell more than optimal Assembly generation, because I am interested more in the former language (and also because programs generated by my compiler are quite fast, the same mandelbrot set generator took only **7s 24ms** to execute on the same old laptop, so I feel like it is good enough, although there is a lot of room for  improvement).

Also, please note that I have a very hard time understanding monads.

## Data types

Starting with the data types, the most important one is `BfCommand`.

```
data BfCommand = GoLeft Int     -- <
               | GoRight Int    -- >
               | Add Int        -- +
               | Sub Int        -- -
               | LoopL Int      -- [
               | LoopR Int      -- ]
               | WriteChar      -- .
               | ReadChar       -- ,
               | BfConst Int    -- ???
               deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The only thing I do not like about this type, is the `BfConst` constructor. It just does not feel like it belongs to this data type, because it was added later (to properly represent `[-]` or `[+]`, which sets selected cell's value to `0`). It is just awkward.

What would be the correct and elegant way of doing something like this?

## Parsing text into instructions

```
newtype BfSource = BfSource [BfCommand] deriving (Show)

parseBf :: String -> BfSource
parseBf =
    optimiseBf . BfSource .
    pairLoops [] [] . countLoopLs 0 .
    reduceConsts . mapMaybe char2bfc
  where
    char2bfc :: Char -> Maybe BfCommand
    char2bfc '<' = Just $ GoLeft 1
    char2bfc '>' = Just $ GoRight 1
    char2bfc '+' = Just $ Add 1
    char2bfc '-' = Just $ Sub 1
    char2bfc '[' = Just $ LoopL 0
    char2bfc ']' = Just $ LoopR 0
    char2bfc '.' = Just WriteChar
    char2bfc ',' = Just ReadChar
    char2bfc _   = Nothing
    countLoopLs :: Int -> [BfCommand] -> [BfCommand]
    countLoopLs _ [] = []
    countLoopLs n (LoopL _:bs) = LoopL n : countLoopLs (n + 1) bs
    countLoopLs n (b:bs) = b : countLoopLs n bs
    reduceConsts :: [BfCommand] -> [BfCommand]
    reduceConsts [] = []
    reduceConsts (LoopL _:Sub 1:LoopR _:bs) = BfConst 0 : reduceConsts bs
    reduceConsts (LoopL _:Add 1:LoopR _:bs) = BfConst 0 : reduceConsts bs
    reduceConsts (b:bs) = b : reduceConsts bs
```

How to rewrite `countLoopLs` and `reduceConsts` in a more elegant way? If not for the pattern matching, I would have done it with a `fold`.

## Controlling the flow of the program

To pair the loops correctly I used a stack approach:

```
pairLoops :: [Int] -> [BfCommand] -> [BfCommand] -> [BfCommand]
pairLoops _      q []           = reverse q
pairLoops st     q (LoopL x:bs) = pairLoops (x:st) (LoopL x : q) bs
pairLoops (s:st) q (LoopR _:bs) = pairLoops st (LoopR s : q) bs
pairLoops st     q (b:bs)       = pairLoops st (b : q) bs
```

The main flaw here is the lack of syntax error checking, but I did not really know how to add it.

## Optimising

This compiler makes very simple optimisations:

- Grouping equal elements (`+++` is represented as `Add 3`)
- Reducing excluding operators (`+++--` is represented as `Add 1`)
- Turning `[-]` and `[+]` into `BfConst 0`

`optimiseBf` does exactly that (excluding the last point, this is done by `reduceConsts`).

```
optimiseBf :: BfSource -> BfSource
optimiseBf (BfSource bs) =
    if bs /= obs
        then optimiseBf (BfSource obs)
        else BfSource obs
  where
    obs = opthelper bs
    opthelper :: [BfCommand] -> [BfCommand]
    opthelper []  = []
    opthelper [x] = [x]
    opthelper (x:y:xs) =
        let r        = reduceBf x y
            single   = fromOne r
            (s1, s2) = fromTwo r
         in case r of
                Zero      -> opthelper xs
                (One _)   -> single : opthelper xs
                (Two _ _) -> s1 : opthelper (s2 : xs)
```

This function groups and throws out excluding instructions. Doing it with this `if`

```
if bs /= obs
    then optimiseBf (BfSource obs)
    else BfSource obs
```

is probably a horrible way to do it, but I could not think of another one.

Reducing individual instructions is done using

```
reduceBf :: BfCommand -> BfCommand -> TwoOrLess BfCommand
data TwoOrLess a = Zero
                 | One a
                 | Two a a
                 deriving (Show, Eq)
```

There is not much to talk about `reduceBf` because it is just hardcoded rules.

## Generating assembly

The final stage. This one was surprisingly easy to do (except the loops part).

```
bf2asm :: Handle -> BfCommand -> IO ()
bf2asm handle (GoLeft x) = hPutStrLn handle $
    "    " ++
        if x == 1
            then "dec rcx"
            else "sub rcx, " ++ show x
bf2asm handle (GoRight x) = hPutStrLn handle $
    "    " ++
        if x == 1
            then "inc rcx"
            else "add rcx, " ++ show x
bf2asm handle (Add x) =
    mapM_ (hPutStrLn handle)
        [ "    mov al, [rcx]"
        , "    " ++
            if x == 1
                then "inc al"
                else "add al, " ++ show x
        , "    mov [rcx], al"
        ]
bf2asm handle (Sub x) =
    mapM_ (hPutStrLn handle)
        [ "    mov al, [rcx]"
        , "    " ++
            if x == 1
                then "dec al"
                else "sub al, " ++ show x
        , "    mov [rcx], al"
        ]
bf2asm handle (LoopL x) =
    mapM_ (hPutStrLn handle)
        [ "_LS" ++ show x ++ ":"
        , "    mov al, [rcx]"
        , "    test al, al"
        , "    jz _LE" ++ show x
        ]
bf2asm handle (LoopR x) =
    mapM_ (hPutStrLn handle)
        [ "    jmp _LS" ++ show x
        , "_LE" ++ show x ++ ":"
        ]
bf2asm handle WriteChar = hPutStrLn handle "    call _printChar"
bf2asm handle ReadChar  = hPutStrLn handle "    call _readChar"
bf2asm handle (BfConst x) =
    mapM_ (hPutStrLn handle)
        [ "    " ++
            if x == 0
                then "xor al, al"
                else "mov al, " ++ show x
        , "    mov [rcx], al"
        ]
```

Is it better to provide a `Handle` and write to it like I did, or maybe this function should just create `String`s?

---

If the need arises, feel free to look at the code as a whole [here](https://github.com/wilbdhm/bfcompiler/tree/b46cf7138840669bfe9c603bde1afd8dc3165607).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BfSource` isn't Brainfuck, it's an intermediate language that's easier to work with. Don't worry about `BfConst` more than about `Add`'s `Int` parameter. You can reuse the `Const` identifier, this is not a library.

```
type BfSource = [BfCommand]

parseBf = optimiseBf . mapAccumL pairLoops []
  . mapAccumL countLoopLs 0 . mapMaybe char2bfc

...
char2bfc '[' = Just $ LoopL undefined -- a hack should look like one
...

countLoopLs n (LoopL _) = (n+1, LoopL n)
countLoopLs n b = (n, b)

pairLoops :: [Int] -> BfCommand -> ([Int], BfCommand)
pairLoops st     (LoopL x) = (x:st, LoopL x)
pairLoops (s:st) (LoopR _) = (st, LoopR s)
pairLoops st     b         = (st, b)

optimiseBf :: BfSource -> BfSource
optimiseBf = head . head . filter ((>1) . length) . group
  . iterate (unfoldr $ uncons . reduceBf)

reduceBf :: [BfCommand] -> [BfCommand]
reduceBf (Add a : Add b : bs) = Add (a + b) : bs
...
reduceBf (LoopL _ : Add 1 : LoopR _ : bs) = BfConst 0 : bs

bf2asm :: Handle -> BfCommand -> IO ()
bf2asm handle = hPutStrLn handle . \case
  GoLeft x -> "    " ++ if x == 1 then "inc rcx" else "add rcx, " ++ show x
  ...
  Add x -> unlines
    [ "    mov al, [rcx]"
    , "    " ++ if x == 1 then "inc al" else "add al, " ++ show x
    , "    mov [rcx], al"
    ]
  ...
```

`Sub` is superfluous. Just replace `Sub 1` with `Add (-1)`. So is one of `GoLeft` or `GoRight`.